# Vanilla install of Apache 2.4 32-bit on Windows 2012 Server becomes unresponsive after a few minutes

Tags: windows-server-2012, apache-2.4

I'm unable to get Apache 2.4.10 to *stay* running on Windows Server 2012.

Here is my setup:

- i5 3Ghz with 8GB RAM, 2TB HD.
- RAM usage never exceeds 2%.
- CPU usage never exceeds 10%.
- I've disabled the firewall, and there is no virus scanner installed.
- MySQL is installed, but not being used right now.
- PHP is not installed, but is required.

The problem:

- I download Apache 2.4.10 32-bit from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/
- Add `ServerName ThinkingMedia` to `httpd.conf`
- Install apache as a service "\apache24\bin\httpd -k install", this is successful
- Log files show no errors.

I'm able to visit the website's address, and see the **"It works!"** message for all domains pointing to that server.

In a console window I run `netstat /n 2` and watch TCP connections. Apache continues to work normally for a while, but after a few minutes `CLOSE_WAIT` conditions begin to happen. All domains pointing to the server are now unresponsive.

I check the Apache logs. There are no new entries. No errors. I check the Windows Event log and there are no new entries. I check Task Manager and there is nothing running with any CPU load. Memory usage is at only 2%.

Apache appears now to be dead, but I don't know why.

Restarting the service repeats the above process. It runs for a few minutes, and then it's not responding.

I've tried both 32-bit and 64-bit builds of Apache. The 64-bit appears to take longer, but the problem persists.

I'm stuck and don't know anything that I can do to diagnose this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Apache over IIS? If you have to use Apache why don't you use Apache on a Linux machine?

Comment: @joeg1ff I have some C# stuff that needs to also run on the box later, but I might switch to ISS as this is not being resolved.

Comment: I would switch to IIS in my experience Apache on Windows is not that great, leave Apache to Linux.